# How to sort images in Views by their position?

Tags: 7, views, entities, media

If you have multiple images uploaded to your node, on the edit mode you can drag those images up and down and position them. How do I set that top image is shown first in Views?

Which sort option is that for the image field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort your view with field_image:delta, ascending